# Issue with subfigures where the image isn't showing

Tags: graphics, subfig

I have the following project, with the issue that whilst the preview for the image shows just fine, including the image in the subfigure/figure environment seems to stop the image from showing. I've tried to locate the source of the issue but have so far come up with nothing. May I please ask for your help with debugging this? My project (minimum document) is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\myMulti}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\myMulti\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\myMulti\textwidth]{figures/masks/04_08_2022_160323Mosaix.jpg}
  \caption{1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\myMulti\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\myMulti\textwidth]{figures/masks/Masked-All Coke.jpg}
  \caption{2}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\myMulti\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\myMulti\textwidth]{figures/masks/Masked-Anisotropic.jpg}
  \caption{3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\myMulti\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\myMulti\textwidth]{figures/masks/Masked-Dark.jpg}
  \caption{4}
  \end{subfigure}
  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[First image](https://i.imgur.com/hT9WnMz.jpg)

[second image](https://i.imgur.com/8xecTUW.jpg)

[third image](https://i.imgur.com/RlwbkLw.jpg)

[fourth image](https://i.imgur.com/kcgcY5O.jpg)

[The project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ggvbvdxpyxyy)

Comment: if you use `example-image` (which is available for tests) do you see the same issue?

Comment: using example-image  I get `LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 556.02637pt on input line 33` but they appear on page 1.  Can you show your log file

Comment: hi @DavidCarlisle, I use "  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\myMulti\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\myMulti\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{4}
  \end{subfigure}" and it shows the image fine...so I guess its an issue with my image?

Comment: does your log warn about them? we can't really debug your image file here as uploading normalises/downgrades them so they look the same but are not (usually) the same jpeg

Comment: oh if you download the images from here do you see same issue?

Comment: So I'm not sure why, but the example image shows fine. Reverting to my images brings up the subfigure minus the images, but there are no bugs in the log!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle downloading the imgur images seems to do the trick!

Comment: ah it confirms an issue with your image (you could delete the question or post a self answer) but beware the images here are "web quality" so they may be ok but they may be too low resolution for high quality print and you may want to fix your original, depending on your use case....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is obviously caused by buggy image files and therefore cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the images, so uploading them to a host and downloading them fixed the issue.